# Tool to use to manage my promotional codes

Tags: mac, software-rec

I need something that I can paste 50 promocodes at a time from iTunes Connect for my iPhone apps. I'd like it if it could maybe treat each one separately, like an item, rather than just a block of text, and give me the option to easily copy one or more to give out, and then some how mark that the promocode has been used so I don't give the some one out twice. I have several iPhone applications that I have promocodes for, as well. This is for the mac, but I have an open mind and iPhone or web suggestions would not be unwelcome (I know, I know, not on SuperUser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using The Hit List which is one of my favorite apps. I just paste in the .txt file and each new line becomes an item that I can then check off and eventually archive. I can even make new lists for each app I have. Can't believe I didn't think of this before! It's perfect.